# Ignore unconverted data from date-time stamp when using strptime

Tags: python-3.5, strptime

A third party API returns me a CSV data containing date time stamp like this:

```
dtval = '2016-10-14 05:09:30+00:00'
```

I have to convert it in the format : `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Here I'm not sure about last +XX:XX of directive:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(dtval, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+XX:XX").strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

I tried followings but did not work:

```
>>>datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-14 05:09:30+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00


>>>datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-14 05:09:30+00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2016-10-14 05:09:30+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%z'
```

Is there any option in the Python3.4+'s datetime module to ignore remainging unconverted data?

I gone through [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) but did not find any such option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit research I found this fix in django's source code :

```
class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """
    Fixed offset in minutes east from UTC. Taken from Python's docs.
    Kept as close as possible to the reference version. __init__ was changed
    to make its arguments optional, according to Python's requirement that
    tzinfo subclasses can be instantiated without arguments.
    """

    def __init__(self, offset=None, name=None):
        if offset is not None:
            self.__offset = timedelta(minutes=offset)
        if name is not None:
            self.__name = name

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.__offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.__name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
    def get_timezone(offset):
        """
        Returns a tzinfo instance with a fixed offset from UTC.
        """
        if isinstance(offset, timedelta):
            offset = offset.seconds // 60
        sign = '-' if offset < 0 else '+'
        hhmm = '%02d%02d' % divmod(abs(offset), 60)
        name = sign + hhmm
        return FixedOffset(offset, name)


def custom_strptime(self, value):
    """Parses a string and return a datetime.datetime.
    This function supports time zone offsets. When the input contains one,
    the output uses a timezone with a fixed offset from UTC.
    Raises ValueError if the input is well formatted but not a valid datetime.
    Returns None if the input isn't well formatted.
    """
    datetime_re = re.compile(
        r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})'
        r'[T ](?P<hour>\d{1,2}):(?P<minute>\d{1,2})'
        r'(?::(?P<second>\d{1,2})(?:\.(?P<microsecond>\d{1,6})\d{0,6})?)?'
        r'(?P<tzinfo>Z|[+-]\d{2}(?::?\d{2})?)?$'
    )
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
    if match:
        kw = match.groupdict()
        if kw['microsecond']:
            kw['microsecond'] = kw['microsecond'].ljust(6, '0')
        tzinfo = kw.pop('tzinfo')
        if tzinfo == 'Z':
            tzinfo = utc
        elif tzinfo is not None:
            offset_mins = int(tzinfo[-2:]) if len(tzinfo) > 3 else 0
            offset = 60 * int(tzinfo[1:3]) + offset_mins
            if tzinfo[0] == '-':
                offset = -offset
            tzinfo = get_timezone(offset)
            kw = {k: int(v) for k, v in kw.items() if v is not None}

        kw['tzinfo'] = tzinfo
        return datetime.datetime(**kw)
```

Comment: is there no other solution?  Having the same issue and this seems to be some overhead solution for me

Comment: @gustavz - I had to write a small script so I used the same without thinking much. If timezone doesn't matter for you just strip out the last zeros and then use `strptime`. and if timezone matters, optimize above code. (BTW I don't know if any standard soln available to this problem, you can google for more)